# is there a way to make outlook 2007 like gmail in functionality and look?

Tags: gmail, microsoft-outlook-2007

is there a way to make outlook 2007 like gmail in functionality and look?

Comment: Are there particular features of one you would like to replicate in the other?

Comment: I'm guessing he mainly wants the threaded view.

Comment: Use Offline Gmail lab or bribe a developer.

Answer (score 4):

No. Gmail is Gmail and Outlook is, well, Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Grab your mails using Gmail (see the setting), and you will receive and send your mails over gmail.

Then enable Offline Gmail from the lab, if will ask you to install an application.

Then syncronise all your online mails with the offline gmail wich is installed on your pc now.

Then you can use gmail or offline gmail to send and receive mails.